# 'int' object not callable when defining function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def gauss(k):
    x, y = np.arange(100.0)/100.0, np.arange(100.0)/100.0
    return((0.5**2/((2*3.14159)*(k**2)))*np.exp(-((1-(x-k))**2)/(2(k**2))).sum()*np.exp(-((1+k-y)**2)/(2(k**2))).sum())
```

And I get an error:

```
'int' object is not callable
```

I've seen answers to questions similar to this one, but I'm still stuck because I can't work out what integer in this code could possibly be causing the proble. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The import is irrelevant: `2(k**2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the `2(k**2)` part (which occurs twice). There's probably an infix operator missing between the two and the parenthesis.

In general, I think that line is trying to do too much at once which makes bugs hard to spot.